# DSP library with LPC encoder / decoder

Tags: signal-processing, speech-synthesis

I'm trying to create a lightweight diphone speech synthesizer. Everything seems pretty straightforward because my native language has pretty simple pronunciation and text processing rules. The only problem I've stumbled upon is pitch control.

As far as I understand, to control the pitch of the voice, most speech synthesizers are using LPC (linear predictive coding), which essentially separates the pitch information away from the recorded voice samples, and then during synthesis I can supply my own pitch as needed.

The problem is that I'm not a DSP specialist. I have used a Ooura FFT library to extract AFR information, I know a little bit about using Hann and Hamming windows (have implemented C++ code myself), but mostly I treat DSP algorithms as black boxes.

I hoped to find some open-source library which is just bare LPC code with usage examples, but I couldn't find anything. Most of the available code (like Festival engine) is tightly integrated in to the synth and it would be pretty hard task to separate it and learn how to use it.

**Is there any C/C++/C#/Java open source DSP library with a "black box" style LPC algorithm and usage examples, so I can just throw a PCM sample data at it and get the LPC coded output, and then throw the coded data and synthesize the decoded speech data?**

Answer (score 4):

it's not exactly what you're looking for, but maybe you get some ideas from this quite sophisticated toolbox: [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/)

Comment: Praat is open source (C++). There's a commandline version for scripting (multiple platforms), and it has its own scripting language, so there are many ways to integrate it into your own software.